# how to scale databases

Tags: database, persistence, scalability

Can someone give me a quick rundown on the old and latest research on scaling databases or storage?
I have heard of master/slave. What else are there? Thanks!

Comment: Quick? You are asking for information that can fill several books.

Answer (score 2):

In general there are two ways to scale a database - horizontal and vertical (which, if the design of your software and database are right, may be mixed together).

Vertical pretty much means bigger computers - more ram, CPU, faster disks etc...

Horizontal means spreading the load across many computers. One example is [sharding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29), another is use of different machines for different data (one data base for customer data, another for product data etc...).

I am not sure what you mean about master/slave? It is a concept that has more to do with backup and failover than scalability.

Comment: Your definitions of vertical/horizontal scalability are backwards. Master/slave configurations are where writes are done to a master server from which data gets copied to read-only replicas.

Comment: @Novikov - quite right about mixing up vertical/horizontal. Good catch.